# First TD for next TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
<table>
    <tr class="here">
        <td class="first">first</td>
        <td class="next" par="http://google.com">next</td>
        <td class="next" par="http://stackoverflow.com">next</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

live: http://jsfiddle.net/C5vSP/

i would like receive with jQuery:

```
<table>
    <tr class="here">
        <td class="first"><a href="http://google.com">first</a></td>
        <td class="next" par="http://google.com">next</td>
        <td class="next" par="http://stackoverflow.com">next</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This must get parameter **par** from first **TD.next** and make link in first TD with this parameter.

Is possible with jQuery? If yes, how?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for answer. For all +1. I have one more problem:

```
<table>
    <tr class="here">
        <td class="first">first</td>
        <td class="next" par="http://google.com">next</td>
        <td class="next" par="http://stackoverflow.com">next</td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="here">
        <td class="first">first</td>
        <td class="next" par="http://yahoo.com">next</td>
        <td class="next" par="http://stackoverflow.com">next</td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="here">
        <td class="first">first</td>
        <td class="next" par="http://cnn.com">next</td>
        <td class="next" par="http://stackoverflow.com">next</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/C5vSP/2/

This add for all .here link google.com instead of google.com, yahoo.com and cnn.com.
I dont can modify html. I can use only jQuery.
How can i make this correctly?

Comment: i think it's possible with jquery, not 100% sure

Comment: After your update I'm not sure what you're looking for by adding the here class to your rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit, is this what you want? [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/granjoy/C5vSP/3/)

```
$("tr.here").each(function (){//Iterate all the <tr/>
    var $html = $(this);
    var $firstTd =  $html.children(":first");//get the first td.
    var url = $firstTd.next().attr("par");//Get the first par value.
    $firstTd.wrapInner('<a href="'+url+'">');//Append the value.
})
```

Answer (score 7):

How's this: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5vSP/1/)**

```
var url =  $('td.next:first').attr('par');
$('td.first').wrapInner('<a href="'+url+'">');
```

Comment: since first isn't a true css selector, you'll end up going faster by moving the first selector to a filter after the native css selector.

Comment: It's a jQuery selector so that's all we need.

Comment: It is a JQuery selector.  The JQuery docs for it say: "Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM ... To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first")."

Answer (score 3):

The selector will look like:

```
myTD = $('table tr.here td.next').filter(':first')
```

I would suggest chaing the parameter "par" to "data-par" so you can say take advantage of Jquery's data() function. The data function reads in any parameters that begin with "data-" Something like...

```
myvar = myTD.data('par');
```

I'm not entirely clear what you mean "make link in first TD with this parameter."  But let's say you want to make the "next" inside the 2nd TD into a link...

```
myTD = $('table tr.here td.next')
newLink = '<a href="' + myvar + '">' + myTD.html() + '</a>';
myTD.html( newLink);
```